# Scipts cgi and suexec

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, cgi, suexec

I have a httpd server

```
SuexecUserGroup         netmet netmet
DocumentRoot            /home/netmet/html
ServerName
ServerAdmin
ErrorLog                /var/log/httpd/netmet.error
TransferLog             /var/log/httpd/netmet.access
DirectoryIndex          index.cgi index.html

AliasMatch              /netmet-cgi-bin/nmHOST-4.*-DETAILS(.*)\.cgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/netmet-cgi-bin/nmHOST-DETAILS$1.cgi
AliasMatch              /netmet-cgi-bin/nmHOST-4.*-SERVICES(.*)\.cgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/html/netmet-cgi-bin/nmHOST-SERVICES$1.cgi
AliasMatch              /netmet-cgi-bin/nmTOP_NforORGA4-.*\.cgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/netmet-cgi-bin/nmTOP_NforORGA.cgi

AddHandler              cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

When I try to access to those scripts with my server, I get **500 internal server error** so I check `error.log` :

```
[Fri Jun 02 09:07:01.467017 2017] [core:notice] [pid 31617] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
suexec policy violation: see suexec log for more details
```

Now the `suexec.log` :

```
[2017-06-02 09:07:26]: uid: (1001/netmet) gid: (1001/netmet) cmd: index.cgi
[2017-06-02 09:07:26]: command not in docroot (/home/netmet/html/index.cgi)
```

After looking on the web a solution, people advice to do

```
~# /usr/lib/apache2/suexec -V
-D SUEXEC_CONFIG_DIR=/etc/apache2/suexec/
-D AP_GID_MIN=100
-D AP_LOG_EXEC="/var/log/apache2/suexec.log"
-D AP_SAFE_PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
-D AP_UID_MIN=100
```

Why **DOC_ROOT** is not displayed ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it after install apache2-suexec-custom:

```
apt-get install apache2-suexec-custom
```

and change config in:

```
/etc/apache2/suexec
```

and restart apache2 service

Comment: Already tried to install it but the thing I don't understand is that after changing the two lines in `/etc/apache2/suexec/www-data`, when I do `/usr/lib/apache2/suexec -V` still shows **AP_DOC_ROOT="/var/www"**

Comment: Do you restart your Apache service?

Comment: I did but no changes appear

Comment: Did you install apache from package or build from sources?

Comment: You can build apache from sources and use --with-suexec-docroot=DIR too.

Comment: The problem is that I did it from package and idk if build and recompile with this command will delete existant files

Comment: ok, i see now that you are using non default user of web server, rename or copy  /etc/apache2/suexec/www-data to /etc/apache2/suexec/netmet

Comment: done and now what's next ?

Comment: and something was changing? what in logs after reload apache2 and run script?

Comment: I solved my problem but the copy of /etc/apache2/suexec/www-data to /etc/apache2/suexec/netmet didn't change anything. I did some tests and the suexec file that apache2 uses seems to be the `/etc/apache2/suexec/www-data`, something strange is that in my httpd.conf the directive `SuexecUserGroup` specify the user and group `netmet` but it looks like he doesn't care about it and still use the user `www-data` but I had enough problems for the moment and everything works so doesn't matter !  Thanks for your help and i'll tag it as solved !